# Does Techiyat Hameisim, resurrection, apply to Non-Jews as well?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, gentiles, messiah, olam-haba-world-to-come, resurrection-of-the-dead

Will righteous non-jews also partake in Techiyat Hameisim, resurrection?  Will they be brought back to life in the time of the Mashiach?

Will Noach? Abraham?  Malki-Tzedek? Shem?  etc.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is yes, they will be resurrected. See from Sukkah 52b:

> The Gemara continues homiletically interpreting verses that relate to the end of days. It is stated: “And this shall be peace: When the Assyrian shall come into our land, and when he shall tread in our palaces, then shall we raise against him seven shepherds, and eight princes among men” (Micah 5:4). The Gemara asks: Who are these seven shepherds? The Gemara explains: David is in the middle; Adam, Seth, and Methuselah are to his right; Abraham, Jacob, and Moses are to his left. And who are the eight princes among men? They are Yishai, Saul, Samuel, Amos, Zephania, Zedekiah, Messiah, and Elijah.

Please note that Adam, Seth, Methuselah, Abraham and Jacob were all prior to the giving of the Torah at Sinai. They are not Jewish. Their status is that of non-Jew.

It should be pointed out in the context of current world affairs (פשר) that there is a distinct possibility this page of Talmud is speaking about the very near future.

Comment: How do you know this Gemara is referring to the time of the Mashiach and that they will be brought back to life?

Comment: @RCW The commentaries to the prophets being quoted state that these posukim are speaking about the Days of Moshiach. “The End of Days” is during the Days of Moshiach. Also, the commentaries to this page, like Rabbeinu Chananel state this.

Answer (score 3):

R [Yechiel Michel Tucazinsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Tucazinsky) in his [Gesher Hachaim](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0940118254) (section 3, chapter 8, part IV) writes, based on Pirkei d'Rabbi Eliezer (34) that the righteous of the Gentiles will also be resurrected.

> I will slay every gentile who will say there is another God... with
>   the death from which there is no revival; whereas I shall make every
>   gentile come to life who declares that there is no other God... R
>   Yonatan said: All the dead will rise again except for the Generation
>   of the Flood...

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there are clear sources indicating that non-Jews will be resurrected (but see [this other answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91978/11501) and comments below)

MyJewishLearning indeed [writes](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/jewish-resurrection-of-the-dead/)

> It is not entirely clear whether only Jews, or all people, are
>   expected to be resurrected at this time.

and R Naftali Silberberg at chabad.org [writes](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1127537/jewish/Who-Will-Be-Resurrected.htm) only about Jews

> Every Jewish soul that ever lived will be resurrected.

(see also [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/moshiach/article_cdo/aid/1127503/jewish/The-Resurrection-Process.htm) from the same author)

There is a well-known Rambam (MT [Hilchot Tshuva 3:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Repentance.3.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that

> the righteous among the nations of the world have a share in the
>   World to Come

but the World to Come can refer to the spiritual after-life, beyond the era of resurrection.

Comment: Have you never looked at Sukkah 52b? The are clearly non-Jews who are resurrected. The position of Chabad is the position they learn from the Rebbe in each generation and the Rebbes teach that with few exceptions all non-Jews will be resurrected for G-d’s Day of Judgement mentioned by the prophets and recorded in midrash.

Comment: Just briefly reviewing your link to the Silverberg article, he is discussing Olam HaBa, not resurrection even though the title to the article is about resurrection. The two are not the same thing.

Comment: @YaacovDeane +1 on your answer. Paraphrasing the few words of Artscroll elucidation of the gemara right before your quote, I answer "Why should I dispute with R Yaacov D seeing that in this field he is my superior"? Still a quote from one the Rebbes of chabad would help - I didn't find these and the chabad.org articles above don't mention them but I know from [previous discussions with you](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69017/11501) that not everyone means the same with olam haba

Comment: If you have access, try learning the Ma’amar of the Rebbe beginning with the words, “להבין ענין תחיית המתים” found in volume 3 of Sefer HaMa’amarim Meluket. This is an excellent introduction to the concept and nomenclature. Additionally, this printed discourse was personally reviewed and edited by the Rebbe. Make sure to look up and learn the sources in the footnotes he points out. It can be found at Hebrewbooks.org

Comment: PS: Just a working class guy trying to help...