# What is the world to come?

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come

Is there a description of the world to come? 
How do we know about it, what is it?

Comment: Are you interested in the arrival of Maschiach? If yes see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69017/11501) Or are you interested in the world of souls where our soul goes after we die? In which case [this](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/282508/jewish/What-Happens-After-Death.htm) might help.

Comment: Yes both, thank you, interested in what is meant when people write “the world to come”.