# What is heaven like for non Jews

Tags: afterlife

Do non Jews who follow the seven laws of Noah get the same reward as a Jew or what is heaven like for us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-Jews (Gentiles) in Olam Haba (Jewish Afterlife)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/883/non-jews-gentiles-in-olam-haba-jewish-afterlife)

Comment: According to many modern rabbis yes and no. Yes, they get to go to heaven but it is not the same. Other rabbis rebuff this. I recommend you see Rabi Asher Meza on this topic.

Comment: If there was nothing to be gained by becoming Jewish, the Torah would not bother making provisions for conversion. But, the gain may be entirely in this world in the form of a more fulfilling life.

Comment: One great Rabbi on YouTube says the lower Gan Eden is experienced by you and what you see is molded by your beliefs.